# Show AutoCompleteTextView's drop down on button click

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a `AutoCompleteTextView` which returns the list of places according to the text entered. The `AutoCompleteTextView` is working fine and returning the required data. However, I am facing a slight problem.
Consider that i am wrote  `lo` in `AutoCompleteTextView` and then pressed a button to search the matching places. The search is working correctly and loading the drop down list of `AutoCompleteTextView` with suggested places. But i can only see the drop down if i enter a 3rd word i.e. `lon` or i edit the word as `l`.
I want the drop down to be visible as soon as the drop down list gets updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For showing drop down on button click use this:

```
autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
```